# invalid column count on line 1

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to load a csv that has 21 columns and 240 rows through phpmyadmin. The most common error message is:
"invalid column count on line 1" (using csv import)

though when using load data, I get:
"error: #1083 – Field separator argument is not what is expected; check the manual"

Columns separated with ,
Columns enclosed with "
Columns escaped with \
Lines terminated with auto (though I've tried \r, \n, \r\n and any combination of the 3)

I have also tried escaping the quotes and commas but it seems to not do anything.

This is the first row of the data:

Denis,NULL,Wirtz,"221Maryland Hall 3400 North Charles Street\, Baltimore\, MD 21236",,410-516-7006,410-516-5528,wirtz@jhu.edu,Theophilus Halley Smoot Professor,NULL,NULL,"K.L. Yap\, S.I. Fraley\, M.M. Thiaville\, N. Jinawath\, K. Nakayama\, J.-L. Wang\, T.-L. Wang\, D. Wirtz\, and I.-M. Shih\, ÒNAC1 is an actin-binding protein that is essential for effective cytokinesis in cancer cellsÓ\, Cancer Research 72: 4085_4096 (2012).D.H. Kim\, S.B. Khatau\, Y. Feng\, S. Walcott\, S.X. Sun\, G.D. Longmore\, and D. Wirtz\, ÒActin cap associated focal adhesions and their distinct role in cellular mechanosensingÓ\, Scientific Reports (Nature) 2:555-568 (2012).S.I. Fraley\, Y. Feng\, G.D. Longmore\, and D. Wirtz\, ""Dimensional and temporal controls of cell migration by zyxin and binding partners in three-dimensional matrix""\, Nature Communications 3:719-731 (2012)P.-H. Wu\, C.M. Hale\, J.S.H. Lee\, Y. Tseng\, and D. Wirtz\, ÒHigh-throughput ballistic injection nanorheology (htBIN) to measure cell mechanicsÓ\, Nature Protocols 7: 155_170 (2012)C.M. Hale\, W.-C. Chen\, S.B. Khatau\, B.R. Daniels\, J.S.H. Lee\, and D. Wirtz\, ÒSMRT analysis of MTOC and nuclear positioning reveals the role of EB1 and LIC1 in single-cell polarizationÓ\, Journal of Cell Science124: 4267-4285 (2011).D. Wirtz\, K. Konstantopoulos\, and P.C. Searson\, ÒPhysics of cancer: the role of physical interactions and mechanical forces in cancer metastasisÓ\, Nature Reviews Cancer 11: 512-522 (2011)",,NULL,http://www.jhu.edu/chembe/faculty-template/DenisWirtz.jpg,Department of Chemical and Biomolecular Engineering,NULL,Whiting School of Engineering,"Postdoctoral\, Physics\, Biophysics. ESPCI\, Paris. 1993 - 1994Ph.D.\, Cemical Engineering. Stanford University. 1993M.S.\, Chemical Engineering. Stanford University. 1989B.S.\, Physics Engineering. Free University of Brussels. 1983-1988",Johns_Hopkins_University

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried importing your CSV in excel ? it can be a good visual indicator of where the problem is...

Comment: What are all those double quotation marks?

Comment: I've actually been exporting it from excel. I tried saving it as a csv and then re-importing it into a new doc and that seemed to work fine. Still an invalid column count though. FYI I'm using excel mac 2011.

Comment: The double quotes are "apparently" how csv files do single quotes within a single cell according to wikipedia. When I export the excel file it automatically puts them in.

Answer (score 0):

There are backslashes in front of commas inside double-quoted strings.  If your utility treats those as escaped commas, they will function as column separators, and you will get the wrong number of columns:

```
"221Maryland Hall 3400 North Charles Street\, Baltimore\, MD 21236"
```

Again, the doubled double-quotes "" are usually a way to escape a single double-quote within a string.  But if the parsing reads it as a string terminator, that's another way it can throw off your column count.

I have seen Excel mess up exported data in many fascinating ways, but this one is new to me.

Comment: So I should unescape the commas? What about the quotes?

Comment: It depends on how phpmyadmin is parsing the file;  you may have to use trial and error to find out what it is expecting.  I would try importing a file where you have done a global find-and-replace on all of the \, combinations.  If they are within double-quoted strings, a plain comma should work.  If that's not the problem, I would try replacing the "" combinations with something else, perhaps a single quote mark, or else a placeholder character that you can fix with an update after the import.  Finally, I would go back to your excel data source and see if there's any way to export clean data.